# How to append value in order to every tuple within a list?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I'm trying to find a way to append value in order to every tuple within a list. Assuming I have the below two lists:

```
List_1:
[('xxx', 1), ('yyy', 2), ('zzz', 3), ('aaa', 1), ('fff', 4), ('bbb', 0)]

List_2:
['1', '3', '4', '20', '11', '15']

Desire outcome:
[('xxx', 1, '1'), ('yyy', 2, '3'), ('zzz', 3, '4'), ('aaa', 1, '20'), ('fff', 4, '11'), ('bbb', 0, '15')]
```

Here is my code and

```
for y in List_1:
        for x in List_2:
            desire_list = [list(y) + [x] for y in List_1]
```

The output will add each individual value from List_2 to each tuple in List_1

```
[[('xxx', 1, '1'), ('yyy', 2, '1'), ('zzz', 3, '1'), ('aaa', 1, '1'), ('fff', 4, '1'), ('bbb', 0, '1')]]
[[('xxx', 1, '3'), ('yyy', 2, '3'), ('zzz', 3, '3'), ('aaa', 1, '3'), ('fff', 4, '3'), ('bbb', 0, '3')]]
```

Very obvious I'm not doing this right... I'm wondering what's the correct way to do this and what if I have multiple lists that I'd like to append the values to List_1 like what I was trying to do from List_2? For example:

```
List_2:['1', '3', '4', '20', '11', '15']
List_3 ['10', '20', '10', '210', '50', '150']

List_1 [('xxx', 1, '1', '10'), ('yyy', 2, '3', '20'), ('zzz', 3, '4', '10'), ('aaa', 1, '20', '210'), ('fff', 4, '11', '50'), ('bbb', 0, '15', '150')]
```

Comment: Variable names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is straightforward using `zip` and tuple unpacking:

```py
>>> [ (x, y, z) for ((x, y), z) in zip(List_1, List_2) ]
[('xxx', 1, '1'), ('yyy', 2, '3'), ('zzz', 3, '4'), ('aaa', 1, '20'),
 ('fff', 4, '11'), ('bbb', 0, '15')]
```

The problem with your attempted solution is that you used nested loops, which iterate over all combinations of one element from `List_1` and one from `List_2`. You don't want all pairs; you only want "parallel" pairs where each element from one list is paired with the element at the same index in the other list. In that situation, use `zip`.

Answer (score 3):

Just use zip and tuple concatenation

```py
>>> lst1 = [('xxx', 1), ('yyy', 2), ('zzz', 3), ('aaa', 1), ('fff', 4), ('bbb', 0)]
>>> lst2 = ['1', '3', '4', '20', '11', '15']
>>> [a + (b,) for a, b in zip(lst1, lst2)]
[('xxx', 1, '1'),
 ('yyy', 2, '3'),
 ('zzz', 3, '4'),
 ('aaa', 1, '20'),
 ('fff', 4, '11'),
 ('bbb', 0, '15')]
```